# Material ui read only rating is not updating when data is ready

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

My rating component is in child component and I am sending data from parent component via props. The issue is MUI rating value is not updating when the data is ready to view.

[image]

**You can see here the text is updating the value but not the rating.**

**Parent Component**

```
<Review details={details} />
```

**Child Component**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import LinearProgress, { linearProgressClasses } from '@mui/material/LinearProgress';
import { AiFillStar } from "react-icons/ai";
import { Avatar, Pagination, Rating } from '@mui/material';
import axios from 'axios';
import Apiurl from '../../Apiurl/Apiurl';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';


const BorderLinearProgress = styled(LinearProgress)(({ theme }) => ({
    height: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    [`&.${linearProgressClasses.colorPrimary}`]: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? 200 : 800],
    },
    [`& .${linearProgressClasses.bar}`]: {
        borderRadius: 5,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? '#1a90ff' : '#308fe8',
    },
}));

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    rating: {
      '& .MuiRating-iconFilled': {
        color: 'white', // Change the filled star color to white
      },
      '& .MuiRating-iconEmpty': {
        borderColor: 'white', // Change the border color to white for empty stars
      },
    },
  }));

const Review = ({ details }) => {
    const [review, setReview] = useState([])
    // const averageRating = review?.average_rating
    const classes = useStyles();
    const handleChangePage = (event, value) => {
        console.log("checking pagination", event, value)
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(Apiurl.particular_course_review)
            .then((res) => setReview(res.data.reviews))
            .then((err) => console.log(err))
    }, [])
    console.log(review, "props", details);
    return (
        <div className='bg-gray-200 p-10 rounded-xl'>
            <h1 className='text-lg font-semibold mb-5'>Review</h1>
            <div className='flex justify-between'>
                <div className='w-3/12'>
                    <div className='rounded-xl text-center text-white p-10' style={{backgroundImage:"linear-gradient(180deg, #17ACC1 0%, #0A2D4C 100%)"}}>
                        <span className='text-lg font-semibold'>{details?.average_rating}</span>
                        {/* <div className='flex justify-center my-4'><AiFillStar /><AiFillStar /><AiFillStar /><AiFillStar /><AiFillStar /></div> */}
                        <div>
                            <Rating name="half-rating-read" defaultValue={details?.average_rating} precision={0.5} readOnly size="small" sx={{color:'white',borderColor:'white'}} className={classes.rating}/>
                        </div>
                        <span>{details?.total_reviews} reviews</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Review;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Bind your `average_rating` in value prop of Rating Component.

```
<Rating name="half-rating-read" defaultValue={details?.average_rating} value={details?.average_rating} precision={0.5} readOnly size="small" sx={{color:'white',borderColor:'white'}} className={classes.rating}/>
```

defaultValue prop is not reactive to data change as it is used for initial value assignment but will not cause re-render.
https://mui.com/material-ui/api/rating/#Rating-prop-value

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help!